# Dynamically load functions

Tags: r

If I define a function in an external file, I have to use `source` to load it in. So if I'm modifying a function, my process looks like:

1. Make changes in file
2. Source
3. Test changes
4. Back to 1

Is there any way to remove #2? E.g. in Octave it just dynamically searches your path to find the appropriate file every time you call a function.

Comment: I believe the answer to be 'no' but since I don't have any documentation to refer you to I won't post it as an actual answer.  I will, however, point you toward devtools and RStudio.  If you're making a package then RStudio+devtools makes it really easy to reload all of your functions with a keyboard shortcut.  You could also then write some automated tests using the RUnit or testthat packages to make the process more streamlined.

Comment: There is an option "Source on Save" in RStudio.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No,

If you make changes to a function, you're always going to have to reload it. However, as mentioned by commenters, there are other options when using RStudio, namely:

1. Source on Save, and;
2. `fix()`

Depending on the complexity of the function, I personally like `fix()` because it immediately reloads the function and it's great for making quick adjustments - but the caveat is that you have to remember to save your changes manually.

When I'm troubleshooting, I generally use `fix` and then copy-paste into my function file.

The `devtools` package offers a range of simplification and streamlining for package development. Which, while it can also be useful for the purposes of reloading, seems to be outside of the scope of your question.